# && condition working as || in do while loop in c

Tags: c, comparison-operators

The `AND` (`&&`) condition evaluates as `OR`(`||`) in this code. For ex., when user inputs numbers **6** and **7**, the output is **12** but when the I replace `&&` with `||` the output is **42**.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b,max,lcm;

    printf("Enter 2 numbers: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

    if(a>b)
    {
        max=a;
    }
    else
    {
        max=b;  
    }

    do
    {
        max++;
    } while(max%a!=0 && max%b!=0);

    lcm=max;
    printf("LCM of %d and %d is %d\n", a,b,lcm);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the `&&` condition is working as an `and` condition, just as it should. When you input `6` and `7`, `max%a` evaluates to `0` when `max` is `12`. At that point `max%a != 0` evaluates to `false` (`false && true == false`), and `max%a != 0 && max%b != 0` evaluates to `false`, and your loop exits. However, `max%a != 0 || max%b != 0` evaluates to `true` (`max%b` is `5` for a `max` of `12` and `b` of `7`, `false || true == true`), so the loop continues.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the `do {..} while (...);` loop to:

```
while (1)
{
   max++;
   if ( max%a == 0 && max%b == 0 )
   {
      break;
   }
}
```

It is so much easier to follow, at least for me.